Clarification on the definition of integrals of nonnegative extended real value functions
Definition
Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a nonnegative extended real-valued measurable function on $X$. The integral of $f$ over $X$ with respect to $\mu$, which is denoted by $\int_Xf~d\mu$, is defined as
$$\int_Xf~d\mu=sup~\left\{\int_X\varphi~d\mu: \varphi~\text{is a simple function for which} ~0\leq \varphi\leq f~\text{on}~ X\right\}$$
For a measurable subset $E$ of $X$, the integral of $f$ over $E$ with respect to $\mu$ is defined to be $\int_Xf\cdot\chi_E~d\mu$ and denoted by $\int_Ef~d\mu$.
My question is how about if $f$ is infinite outside the measurable subset $E$ of $X$, won't that make $f\cdot\chi_E$, undefined?

As a convention, $(f \cdot \chi_E)(x) = 0$ for $x \notin E$, even if $f(x) = \pm \infty$.
